# TextBox not resetting focus when reopening the dropdown in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a customized ComboBox to handle the text input and filter the itemsource. The problem I'm having is when I open the ComboBox the textBox is focused and let me write in it, then if I close and open it again, the TextBox is not focused and I cant write anything inside. I've discovered that the first time the comboBox is opening it is setting the focus on the TextBox but when I close it the TextBox keeps its `IsFocused` property true so when reopening the problem happens. It's just when opening and reopening clicking the comboBox because if I click outside the ComboBox to close it and then open it again everything works nice.

Here is the customized style I wrote and the ComboBox I'm using.

```
<Style x:Key="FilteringComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Coves"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Border x:Name="TopBorder" 
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        BorderBrush="Grey"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="10,0,1,0">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#e3e3e5" Offset="0.65"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                        Name="ToggleButton" 
                        Template="{DynamicResource FilteringComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                        Grid.Column="2" 
                        Focusable="false"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <TextBlock Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Path=Data.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Visibility="Visible" Foreground="#37465c"
                                        Padding="3,3,23,3" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" MaxWidth="215" MinWidth="100"
                                Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Path=Data.FilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                                                              
                                Foreground="#37465c" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                        <Popup x:Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="215">
                                <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                    MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderThickness="1"
                                            BorderBrush="#888">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.504,1.5" StartPoint="0.504,0.03">
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#e3e3e5" Offset="0.65"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried adding this event handler to remove the focus but it isn't working

```
private static void QuantityBox_IsMouseCapturedWithin(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var qBox = sender as ComboBox;

    if (qBox.IsDropDownOpen == false)
    {
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that this helps someone, the erratic behaviour was happening because I was using these triggers:

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True"/>
    <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
    <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
</Trigger>
```

The triggers were ment to handle the visibility toggle between the TexBlock and the TextBox (showing the TextBlock when the ComboBox was inactive and the TextBox when it is focused so the user can type and filter). 
So I removed the triggers and handled that behaviour in a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseCapturedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseCaptured",
        typeof(bool), typeof(QuantitiesBoxBehaviours),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, MouseCapturedPropertyChangedCallback));        

public static bool GetMouseCaptured(UIElement element)
{
    return (bool)element.GetValue(MouseCapturedProperty);
}

public static void SetMouseCaptured(UIElement element, bool command)
{
    element.SetValue(MouseCapturedProperty, command);
}

private static void MouseCapturedPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var qBox = d as ComboBox;
    bool value = GetMouseCaptured(qBox);
    if (qBox != null && value)
    {
        qBox.IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged += QBox_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged;
        qBox.DropDownOpened += QBox_DropDownOpened;
    }
}

private static void QBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var qBox = sender as ComboBox;
    var template = qBox.Template;
    var txtBox = template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", qBox) as TextBox;
    var txtBlock = template.FindName("ContentSite", qBox) as TextBlock;
    txtBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    txtBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private static void QBox_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var qBox = sender as ComboBox;
    var template = qBox.Template;
    var txtBox = template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", qBox) as TextBox;
    var txtBlock = template.FindName("ContentSite", qBox) as TextBlock;

    if (qBox.IsDropDownOpen == false)
    {
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        txtBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        txtBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        qBox.ItemsSource = _presentationQuantities;
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

That solved the problem and now it's working great, that property was set to the ComboBox.